# fail2ban: apache-auth isn't banning failed login attempts

Tags: apache, fail2ban

Trying to implement fail2ban on a Linux Mint 17.1 and cant seem to get it to ban me after multiple login attempts against apache-auth.
I followed [this guide](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/02/13/how-to-protect-ssh-and-apache-using-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-linux/) to get started.
I think its a problem with the apache-auth regex but cant get it right.

jail.local

```
[apache] 
enabled = true 
port = 80,443
filter = apache-auth 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
##ignoreip = 192.168.3.70

##To block the remote host that is trying to request suspicious URLs,     use the below jail. 
[apache-overflows] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-overflows 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 192.168.3.70

##To block the remote host that is trying to search for scripts on the     website to execute, use the below jail. 
[apache-noscript] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-noscript 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 192.168.3.70

##To block the remote host that is trying to request malicious bot,     use below jail. 
[apache-badbots] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = apache-badbots 
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*error.log 
maxretry = 3 
bantime = 600 
ignoreip = 192.168.3.70

##To stop DOS attack from remote host. 
[http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
##ignoreip = 192.168.3.70 
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

apache-auth.conf

```
[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf
[Definition]
failregex = ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01797: )?client denied by server configuration: (uri )?\S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01617: )?user .*? authentication failure for "\S*": Password Mismatch(, referer: \S+)?$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01618: )?user .*? not found(: )?\S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01614: )?client used wrong authentication scheme: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH\d+: )?Authorization of user \S+ to access \S* failed, reason: .*$ 
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH0179[24]: )?(Digest: )?user .*?: password mismatch: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH0179[01]: |Digest: )user `.*?' in realm `.+' (not found|denied by provider): \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01631: )?user .*?: authorization failure for "\S*":(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01775: )?(Digest: )?invalid nonce .* received - length is not \S+(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01788: )?(Digest: )?realm mismatch - got `.*?' but expected `.+'(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01789: )?(Digest: )?unknown algorithm `.*?' received: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01793: )?invalid qop `.*?' received: \S*(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
        ^%(_apache_error_client)s (AH01777: )?(Digest: )?invalid nonce .*? received - user attempted time travel(, referer: \S+)?\s*$
```

apache-common.conf

```
_apache_error_client = \[[^]]*\] \[(error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+:\S+\d+\])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\]
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:42.143209 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025] [client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:43.216097 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025] [client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:44.124570 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025][client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:45.104747 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025][client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:46.001161 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025][client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:46.871802 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025][client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
[Thu Aug 02 23:03:47.843740 2018] [auth_basic:error] [pid 8025][client 192.168.3.60:54788] AH01618: user aaa not found: /SEC/test.php
```

As I said I think the problem is in the regex, since the http-get-dos jail worked fine. The regex for apache-common.conf doesn't look right since my log files seem to follow a different standard, BUT I'm not sure if that's true or how to properly format the regex.

ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem

I had to change the line in apache-common.conf to the following;

```
_apache_error_client = \[[^]]*\] \[(error|\S+:\S+)\]( \[pid \d+\])? \[client <HOST>(:\d{1,5})?\]
```

The difference being in the PID section. I used [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to work the expression until it matched.

Comment: This was [fixed upstream](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/ea2a13946e944d6ff5e0875e922a004dc3d9bdc3#diff-8c06db82508e1b23b0afa33eb816954cR11) a considerable number of years ago.